# Can I just run away and pretend nothing happened if things start smoldering around me?

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants

In the Reign of Giants DLC, summer introduces Overheating for the character and for nearby objects as well. If you stay in one place long enough in the middle of the day, things will start smoking. If they're not extinguished fast, they will begin to burn and nobody wants that in Don't Starve.

But is it okay to simply pack your stuff and leave the smoldering objects off-screen fast? Will they not keep smoking and eventually burn?

Comment: It's what I do in real life.

Comment: @Studoku Hah. Nice.

Also, I have a lot of experience with Don't Starve but none with the newest DLC, so unfortunately I can't help you.

Comment: You'd be better off leaving *before the smoldering begins*, as things will not burn that are too far away from any active players.  You'd be pushing your luck if something is smoking and you just run away.

Comment: Sounds ok, but how do I know when to start running away if there are not signs things are about to start smoking?

Answer (score 2):

One thing I like about Don't Starve is that unlike Minecraft and a lot of other sandboxes, everything that has been loaded continues doing stuff, even if you're off the screen. So yes, they will burn to ashes.

Answer (score -1):

I have the DLC and while I haven't played in a while, I remember that it was somewhat of a bug at the time. I believe it was because if you move a certain distance off screen, the game essentially pauses all entities. I believe the range is a few screen lengths, but I really don't remember. I'm fairly certain they didn't fix it, but if its still in the game then it is definitely possible to do, even though it kinda ruins the point of a survival game if you exploit bugs to survive.